# Returning a value from php to swf

Tags: php, actionscript, file-transfer

I am trying to transfer a movie-clip staged in a swf(on local machine) to a remote server. Below is a part of the action-script code concerned with it;

```
function createJPG(mc:MovieClip, n:Number, fileName:String) {

trace("sdf:");
var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width,mc.height);
jpgSource.draw(mc);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(n);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);
trace("jpegStream::"+jpgStream);
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream");

var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://example.com/arts/savefile.php?name=" + fileName + ".jpg");

jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;


var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
trace("navigatetoURL:");

sendToURL(jpgURLRequest);    }
```

The php script in the remote server to save the file is;

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if( isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) ) {

    $imageFile='images/'.$_GET['name'];
    $fp = fopen($imageFile, 'w+');

    // get bytearray
    fwrite($fp, $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']);
    fclose($fp);

    if( file_exists($imageFile) ) {
        echo 'File saved.';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error: Problem writing the file.';
    }
} 
else {
    echo 'Error: Not data available to write the file.';
}
?>
```

I want to close the swf when the upload is complete., I would like to know how to return a value(may be a number which I intend to use to indicate completion of file transfer) from the php script to the swf and how to receive that value in the swf?

Would really appreciate any help.
Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLLoader supports an `Event.COMPLETE` event, which is fired when your remote operation returns data and that data has been stored in `URLRequest.data`.

From PHP, the data that you echo is what Flash will receive, so you might want to consider a more complex data type than a single string, maybe use json and pass an object that looks like:

```
{result:1,message:"some message"};
```

This gives you a simple 1/0 result value for easy checking and a string message for output to the user. You would do that in PHP by creating an associative array and encoding it with `JSON.encode()`.

Then on the Flash side you will add an event listener to your URLLoader to detect the COMPLETE event, and use the JSON class from the Adobe core library to decode your PHP output to a useable object.

Answer (score 0):

I always use AMFPHP nowadays http://sourceforge.net/projects/amfphp/ . Gotoandlearn has a nice free tutorial on it http://www.gotoandlearn.com/ .